# How to prevent Chrome interference with setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

My JavaScript setInterval call is setup to run my callback every 30 seconds. But it is not firing at expected frequency when the tab stays in background for sometime.
Chrome does throttling of timers and i have seen callback being called at 1 min frequency after 5 mins or so of tab staying in background.

But this affects my app because if my backend doesn’t receive heartbeat every 30 seconds it will kick my connection.

How to ensure my callback runs every 30 second irrespective of tab staying in background or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)